# CPLEX gets stuck in "Performing restart"

Tags: cplex, benders-decomposition, branch-and-cut

During solving my problem using generic lazy cuts (in Benders decomposition fashion), the solver gets stuck logging out "Performing restart 2" for several hours (while the time limit is 30 min), till I quit it manually .

Based on my searches this situation roots in "Dynamic search" parameter (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=parameters-mip-dynamic-search-switch), so I turned it off, but the problem still exists.

Comment: If you throttle CPLEX down to a single thread does it still happen?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It got better, i.e., passes some instances that used to stuck, but, still remains on "Performing restart" phases for others

Comment: Is "performing restart 2" the last message you get in the log, or does CPLEX add any details after that?

Comment: It is the last thing. I notice that, in all cases, "Performing restart 1"  takes only few seconds and then "Performing restart 2" immediately appears and gets stuck. Again, in some cases it remains idle for almost a day, till I manually stop the solver.

Comment: Setting the [repeatpresolve](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=parameters-mip-repeat-presolve-switch) parameter to `0` might help.

Comment: You might want to ask about this in the [IBM Decision Optimization forum](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer?communitykey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7).

Comment: @Samarth, thanks for your comment. It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @prubin, thanks. I will pose the question there as well.